# sending data from one thread on host machine to some kind of service thread running on the other machine over network

Tags: python, multithreading, ipc

I want to send some commands from my host machine to the other machine over the network.

What I want is some kind of listener or service thread which is running all the time on the other machine and soon it encounters a command from the host act accordingly.

How can I achieve this in python?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing `IPC` (interprocess communication) with `RPC` (remote procedure call). IPC is something that happens exclusively locally while RPC is something that you can use to execute stuff on a remote system.

What you want to do here is basic client-server communication scenario so I suggest you look at the thousands of tutorials on the Internet how to achieve that. A properly implemented server has one or multiple service listeners so the scenario you are referring to is a pretty standard one.